# Bar Chart with Vertical Axis Max value set but can't see data label

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2012, axis-labels

I have a report where I have set the Max Value for my Axis Range.  However once rendered and the bar graph has exceeded the Max value for the Axis I can't see my data labels.  I have tried playing with the smart labels but to no avail.  How can I see the data label for my bar graph once it exceeds the Max Value for the Axis?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Increase the Max value on the vertical axis (or just set it back to auto)?

Comment: I can't set it to Auto.  The business has requested to cap it at a certain value

Comment: Are they really that bothered about what a value over 40 is then, other than its a value that exceeds 40?

Comment: Unfortunately yes